# Understanding why the error 'result is not defined' is being received

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm relatively new to MySQL/Node.js and I've been trying to put something together, but I keep encountering an error with my code.

```
app.get("/", function(request, response){
    var q = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users';
    connection.query(q, function (error, results){
        if (error) throw error;
        var count = results[0].count;
        res.send("We have " + count + "users in our database");
    });
});
```

However, on the 'res.send' line I have a warning saying that the 'res is not defined'.

Two questions:

1. Why do I receive this error, and what do I need to change?
2. More broadly, why does this error occur and what should I do in the future to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature has `response` as a parameter and you are trying to use `res` (not defined anywhere). So change `res` to `response`.